# How do i build my react front end and django backend application for a 32 bit system?

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I am working on an application for a 32 bit PC. i have almost completed the front end and backend. now i want to build executable for my application (if that's even possible in case of react and django). I want to run the application on a 32 bit PC. I myself have a 64 bit machine. Please guide me how do i do that. For django application i can create a virtual environment? but would that require me to install python on the system i want to install the app. and in case of react how can i build it from my PC to work on 32 bit PC. Thanks in advance.

Comment: YOu should now try electrojs with react. google it, it is very easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found that for the front end based in react one can build an executable file and an installer using electron. Electron is an open-source software framework developed and maintained by GitHub. It allows for the development of desktop GUI applications using web technologies: it combines the Chromium rendering engine and the Node.js runtime. You can read more about electron on [Electron website](https://www.electronjs.org/).

And for the backend in django there are tools to make exe file of a python-django but making an exe file for django project is not the best practice.

Other alternative to use in javascript/React is sqlite3 [npm package sqlites](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3)